anchor shows errors "no associated item named `__anchor_private_gen_idl_type` found for struct `anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount` in the current scope"
I run my code, and it shows, looks like I need to intro pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>, but I did, you can get more information from my code below

error[E0599]: no associated item named `__anchor_private_insert_idl_defined` found for struct `anchor_spl::token::Mint` in the current scope
   --> programs/sol404/src/instructions/createmint.rs:153:10
    |
153 | #[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `Mint`
    |
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Accounts` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)


error[E0599]: no associated item named `__anchor_private_insert_idl_defined` found for struct `anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount` in the current scope
   --> programs/sol404/src/instructions/createmint.rs:153:10
    |
153 | #[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `TokenAccount`
    |
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Accounts` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)



here is my code, I try to create a mint and a ATA account, and I used
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateMint<'info> {
    // Use ADMIN_PUBKEY as constraint, only the specified admin can invoke this instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    // The PDA is both the address of the mint account and the mint authority
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"jelly"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = jelly_token_mint,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    
    ///CHECK: Using "address" constraint to validate metadata account address, this account is created via CPI in the instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&jelly_token_mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub jelly_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,


    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = jelly_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,


    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}


and here is my cargo.toml, I am not sure whether it is a version problem
[package]
name = "sol404"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "sol404"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"]}
mpl-token-metadata = "4.1.2"
solana-program = "1.18.11"


I can't get any useful information from google, and GPT, anyone can help me?

Without seeing the full code, this is a shot in the dark, but have you tried importing anchor_spl::{token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount}}? If that still doesn't work, you can start from a working example like https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/auction-house/programs/auction-house/src/lib.rs and modifying it as needed

In Cargo.toml, please try to add "anchor-spl/idl-build" to idl-build.
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]


Thanks @dev4all.sol! I'm not the question asker, but I did get a lot of function or associated item not found in 'Mint' errors and making this change fixed it. This is one of the first Anchor programs I have made that uses SPL tokens, so it sounds as if we are making this change to explicitly tell Anchor that we're using SPL when building the IDL?

Np! Yes it does - it is a new feature since Anchor 0.30.0

Can confirm this works in anchor 0.29.0.

1st Oct, 2024.
In anchor v0.30.1, solana-cli v1.18.24, rustc v1.81.0
programs/XXX/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "XXX"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "XXX"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["metadata"]}

